# Set woocommerce single product as home page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to set up a woocommerce shop, the aim is to make a product page ( not shop page ) as the site home page.
I tried following shortcode but this displays the products archive page :

```
[product id="" sku=""]
```

Or i missed something ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Did you specify the desired product id?

To get the product id for a product, go to Dashboard -> Products.

Hover over the desired product and the ID will be displayed.

Alternately, click on "Edit" for the desired product and the post ID is visible in the address bar "post=NUMBER&action=edit"

Once you have that, create a new page and insert the shortcode that uses this ID. In the case of product/post ID 17:

```
[product id="17"]
```

Then go to Settings -> Reading and set homepage to this new static page.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response and yes i specified id before i posted my issue :)